# String was not recognized as a valid datetime exception with DateTime.PraseExact

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert date time in to a particular format and save it in to a variable of type Object , but I am facing the error as **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**

below the code which I tried

```
string regDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/07/2015 19:41:06 PM", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The input will be in the format of "05/07/2015 19:41:06 PM" and i want the output in the mm/dd/yyyy format with hours-mins-secs also.

Comment: ParseExact the input format (i.e. with / and secs) to a Date, then call its  ToString with the desired output format

Comment: Time is in 24 hour format cannot take AM / PM as it is 12 hour format

Comment: `Convert.ToString` is not necessary in that code since you already have a string literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you get is reasonable, because the string you pass hasn't the exact format, you pass to the `ParseExact`.

Please try the following:

```
var regDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/07/2015 19:41:06 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Furthermore, there is no need you convert a string to a string, like you did here `Convert.ToString("05/07/2015 19:41:06 PM")`.

Check this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rhmvaL).

Comment: Even this code is giving the same error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

Comment: @Henriques please check it again. I did a correction. Thanks !

Comment: This is working fibe but i need only 2 parts of year i.e YY, but when i changes the above to "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt" its giving the same error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: @Henriques what you mean saying that you only need the 2 parts of years? The reason you were getting this error, is the fact that you try to parse a string and create a `DateTime` using a method, in which you state explicitly the format of the string. If the string has not the proper format, then the parse will fail raising an exception. This is the purpose of using this method.

Comment: @Henriques When we parse a string, we want to create an object based on this. Sometimes, we might want to parse a string, which is the string representation of a number. Other times, we might want to parse a string, which is the string representation of a date time and so on and so forth. Basically, there is a simple theory behind this Parse the input. If parse succeeds you get that your are looking for. While if the parse failed something get wrong. Nothing more, nothing less. On the other hand when we want to have the string representation object, we can instruct how we want it.

Comment: @Henriques Specifically, if you need to display the datetime you created from the above parsing at this form `MM/dd/yy`, you simply have to call this `regDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy")`. That's all. But there isn't any connection between the latter and the problem with `ParseExact`. I hope now this is clear.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment or I would.  You need to combine Christos' answer and Imranullah Khan's comment

```
var regDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/07/2015 19:41:06", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var regDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/07/2015 07:41:06 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can't include AM/PM with 24 hour times (19:41:06).  So either drop the PM and tt or include the tt and change the HH to hh and then change the time to 07:41:06.